# Fatal error in Dev-Pascal

Tags: pascal

I am using Linux to write Pascal and C++ program. I have a problem. The compiler told me that I have an error :

> IMPLEMENTATION expected.

Please help me. I'm still an amateur(sorry if I have a wrong dictate)`

```
unit GLOBAL;

interface

 CONST
  M_Text = 500;
  DoDaiDong = 80;


  SoDongManHinh: byte = 24;

  DongBatDau: byte = 1;

  ESC         = #27;
  PHome       = #71;
  PEnd        = #79;
  PPgUp       = #73;
  PPgDn       = #81;
  PLeft       = #75;
  PRight      = #77;
  PDown       = #80;
  PUp         = #72;
  PIns        = #82;
  PDel        = #83;

  F1          = #59;
  F2          = #60;
  F3          = #61;
  F4          = #62;
  F5          = #63;
  F6          = #64;
  F7          = #65;
  F8          = #66;
  F9          = #67;
  F10         = #68;
 TYPE
  T_TEXT = 0..M_TEXT;
  St80 = String[80];

 VAR

  TEXTE : ARRAY[T_TEXT] OF STRING[DoDaiDong];
  N_TEXT : T_TEXT;
  Y_TEXT : T_TEXT;

  X_TEXT : byte;

  X, Y : byte;
  Dong1, I_TEXT: Integer;

  InsOvr : (Inserte, Overwrite);

  Name : String[80];
  F: Text;

  KetThuc, VeDOS: Boolean;

  LookFlag : Boolean;

  Ch: Char;
  ChByte : Byte;
(----------------------------------------------------------------------)
Implementation


End.
```

Comment: This is not C++ code.

Comment: rephrasing the question

Comment: @Phani since you removed a reference to Pascal in the question, this makes even less sense (since the code does appear to be Pascal).

Comment: It has been a very long time since I worked with any Pascal dialect, but guessing that you need to put something in `Implementation`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have just compiled the given code successfully. There was only one problem. You need either to remove the line

`(----------------------------------------------------------------------)`

either to comment it properly (using proper brackets). The three following ways are allowed in Pascal:

```
{----------------------------------------------------------------------}
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------*)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If the error persists you need to find the problem more precisely and start a new question. The given sample does not contain other syntax errors except mentioned above.